# How can I define multiple instances in molecule which differ only in name?

Tags: docker, testing, ansible, molecule

I've got a `molecule.yml` which looks a bit like this:

```yaml
dependency:
  name: galaxy
driver:
  name: docker
platforms:
  - name: testohpc-compute-0
    image: docker.io/pycontribs/centos:7
    pre_build_image: true
    groups:
      - testohpc_compute
    command: /sbin/init
    tmpfs:
      - /run
      - /tmp
    volumes:
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
    networks:
      - name: net1
```

How can I define another instance, say `testohpc-compute-2` which is exactly the same except for name? Do I really need to copy all the definition from `-1` again?

Furthermore, if there's a way of reusing an instance definition, can I share it between scenarios?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of yaml anchor and merge key features. You can find a basic explanation on [Learn yaml in Y minute](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/).

In your specific case, here is a possible solution.

```yaml
platforms:
  - &default_platform
    name: testohpc-compute-0
    image: docker.io/pycontribs/centos:7
    pre_build_image: true
    groups:
      - testohpc_compute
    command: /sbin/init
    tmpfs:
      - /run
      - /tmp
    volumes:
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
    networks:
      - name: net1
  - <<: *default_platform
    name: testohpc-compute-2
```

**Note**: anchors and merge keys can only be used in the same yaml file. So this will not work between different scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want exactly the same configuration for `testohpc-compute-2`, you can use environnement variable:

```yaml
dependency:
  name: galaxy
driver:
  name: docker
platforms:
  - name: testohpc-compute-${NUMBER:-0}
    image: docker.io/pycontribs/centos:7
    pre_build_image: true
    groups:
      - testohpc_compute
    command: /sbin/init
    tmpfs:
      - /run
      - /tmp
    volumes:
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
    networks:
      - name: net1
```

Then to execute the two instances:

```sh
~|⇒  mol test
# Executes instance testohpc-compute-0
~|⇒  NUMBER=2 mol test
# Executes instance testohpc-compute-2
```

Comment: That only creates one instance at once though right? I want to create both instances at the same time.

Comment: Yes one instance at once. Answer from @Zeitounator creates two instance at once.